# Add rows to database dynamically

Tags: android, database

I have created a database program where I am able to add the data and retrieve it as well but I am stuck as to how do I increase the rows dynamically. If I give 2 rows or 4 rows in a go then I am able to do that like

```
public long insertInDb(String rowOne, String rowTow)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, rowOne);
    initialValues.put(KEY_MOBILE_NUMBER, rowTwo);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Now If want to add these data as many times as user clicks add more button. Then is overwriting the same row again and again. How do I insert in the database so that it creates a new row next to the previous row. And I retrieve it too with the row ID.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the schema of your table? Have you added a _id column to your table which acts as the primary key and set it to autoincrement.

You may declare it in this way

```
_id int primary key autoincrement
```